When using RegQueryValueExW how can I get the entire string which is an REG_SZ?
I should get ABCDEFG, but I only got A.
UPDATE: I added my current adjusted code and an example screen shot.
/// UNICODE version
        DWORD NEW_dwType;
        HKEY NEW_hKey = 0;
        char NEW_value[1024];
        DWORD NEW_value_length = 1024;
        LONG lResult;
        LPTSTR lpEnd;

        LPTSTR lpSubKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers";

        // RegOpenKeyExW();
        // lResult = RegOpenKeyEx (hKeyRoot, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

        ///     OPEN
        lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &NEW_hKey);

        ///     QUERY
        LONG WResult;
        WResult = RegQueryValueExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"C:\\こんにちは\\Test.exe", 0, &NEW_dwType, (LPBYTE)NEW_value, &NEW_value_length);

        RegCloseKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);

        // Convert char to std::string
            string NEW_text_001 = NEW_value;

        // Convert std::String to std::wstring for the message box.
            std::wstring WideString001 = std::wstring(NEW_text_001.begin(), NEW_text_001.end());

        // Concatenate the Wide String for the message box.
            WideString001 = L"Reading from the Registry   UNICODE version\n\nC:\\こんにちは\\Test.exe   REG_SZ   Value data =\n\n[" + WideString001 + L"]\n\nThis should be ABCDEFG" ;

        // Convert std::wstring to const wchar_t* for the message box.
            const wchar_t* CWStringP001 = WideString001.c_str();    // This should be the result that I am looking for.

        MessageBoxExW(nullptr, CWStringP001, L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);

    }

I tried manipulating all of what you see, and this is the closest that I have so far. One letter. The correct first letter, but missing all the rest of the letters.
UPDATE of adjusted code
/// UNICODE version

    wchar_t NEW_value[8];      // [ABCDEFG] + 1   is 8 in length.
    DWORD NEW_value_length = sizeof(NEW_value);

    DWORD NEW_dwType;
    HKEY NEW_hKey = 0;

    LONG lResult;
    LPTSTR lpEnd;

    LPTSTR lpSubKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers";

    // lResult = RegOpenKeyEx (hKeyRoot, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    ///     OPEN
    lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &NEW_hKey);

        if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
                    {
                        MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"ERROR\n\nKey not found\n\nvia RegOpenKeyExW", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"ERROR\n\n opening key\n\nvia RegOpenKeyExW", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"SUCCESS\n\n opening key\n\nvia RegOpenKeyExW", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
            }



    ///     QUERY

    LONG WResult;

    WResult = RegQueryValueExW(NEW_hKey, L"C:\\こんにちは\\Test.exe", 0, &NEW_dwType, (LPBYTE)NEW_value, &NEW_value_length);

        if (WResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (WResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
                    {
                        MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"ERROR\n\nKey not found\n\nvia RegQueryValueExW", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"ERROR\n\n Querying key\n\nvia RegQueryValueExW", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"SUCCESS\n\n Querying key\n\nvia RegQueryValueExW", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
            }

    RegCloseKey(NEW_hKey);

    int i23 = sizeof(NEW_value);
    std::string ss23 = to_string(i23);

    std::wstring WideString001(NEW_value, NEW_value_length / sizeof(wchar_t));
    std::wstring WideString002 = L"WideString002"; //std::wstring(StLength.begin(), StLength.end());
    std::wstring WideString003 = L"WideString003"; // std::wstring(ss23.begin(), ss23.end());


    // Concatenate the Wide String for the message box.
        WideString001 = L"Reading from the Registry   UNICODE version\n\nC:\\こんにちは\\Test.exe   REG_SZ   Value data =\n\n[" + WideString001 + L"]\n\nWhich is length [" + WideString002 + L"]\n\nThis should be ABCDEFG\n\nSize of sizeof(NEW_value) = [" + WideString003 + L"]";

    // Convert std::wstring to const wchar_t* for the message box.
        const wchar_t* CWStringP001 = WideString001.c_str();    // This should be the result that I am looking for.

    MessageBoxExW(nullptr, CWStringP001, L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);

}

I do not have enough points to show an image here.
Also, I tried the quote thing but it shoves this all together and removes indentations and line returns.
This is what is in the messagebox:
UNICODE version
Reading from the Registry   UNICODE version
C:\こんにちは\Test.exe   REG_SZ   Value dat =
[ABCDEFG
blank
blank
There should be a ] bracket next past the end of the string ABCDEFG like this [ABCDEFG] then some more text. I put the brackets in to force the program to tell me exactly what is the result. With this I see that the rest of the message is missing, therefore I guess that something is wrong with the result.
From RegQueryValueExW I think that the result should give me NEW_value which should be the value that is showing in the registry. It starts out right by showing ABDEFG. It does not end right with showing the next part of the messagebox text. I need help finding what I am doing wrong in my code and how to fix it.
If I set wchar_t NEW_value[8];      // ABCDEFG + 1   is 8 in length.
or larger wchar_t NEW_value[1024];  // Either way 8 or 1024.
I get success opening the key.
I get success querying the key.
It shows the text but nothing past that in the message box.
If I set wchar_t NEW_value[7];  // or 6 or 5
I get success opening the key.
I get an error querying the key.

Since you're using RegQueryValueExW the data returned will be a wide string. You get only the first character because the second is 0 because those two bytes are a single  wchar_t.

@RetiredNinja, I changed
    char NEW_value[1024];  

to
std::wstring NEW_value;
Now I get
WResult = RegQueryValueExW(NEW_hKey, L"C:\こんにちは\Test.exe", 0, &NEW_dwType, (LPBYTE)NEW_value, &NEW_value_length);
error: invalid cast from type 'std::__cxx11::wstring
{aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>}
to type 'LPBYTE {aka unsigned char*}    Also, I do not know how to put spaces and new lines in the comments.

Microsoft says,
"If the data has the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ type,
the string may not have been stored with the proper terminating
null characters. Therefore, even if the function returns ERROR_SUCCESS,
the application should ensure that the string is properly terminated
before using it; otherwise, it may overwrite a buffer." I get ERROR_SUCCESS.
I am using REG_SZ. Maybe that is the problem, but I have not found how to fix this.

wchar_t NEW_value[1024]; DWORD NEW_value_length = sizeof(NEW_value); std::wstring WideString001(NEW_value, NEW_value_length / sizeof(wchar_t)); may work.

Try wchar_t NEW_value[1024]; and after you got the data std::wstring WideString001 = NEW_value; BTW the code you show shouldn't get data from the registry at all because RegQueryValueExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, ... will try reading from the root key and not from the subkey you're targeting at.

@RetiredNinja, I get the ENTIRE REG_SZ STRING ! Thank you so much.  Even when I add Unicode letters like this: ABCこんにちはDEFG it STILL WORKS ! I tried it with spaces in the string like this: A B C こ ん に ち は D E F    G and it STILL WORKS ! Wow! Thank you so much. But, it only shows one bracket "[" before the string like this: "[A B C こ ん に ち は D E F    G" in all the variations now. Is the length of the NEW_value_length being set at wchar_t NEW_value[1024] causing a problem? I have been studying how to trim the wchar_t NEW_value[1024] to a smaller size to maybe fix this. Any ideas? Thank you!

@Halfix, Thank you. When I try this: L"HKEY LongerHKEY;
LongerHKEY = L"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"; It says error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t [85]' to 'HKEY {aka HKEY__*}' in assignment. I am not certain what you are telling me. I open with RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &NEW_hKey);. and I close with RegCloseKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);. In between opening and closing, that seemed to be enough to work. I have not found documentation on this. Please explain further what you are telling me.
"

From RegOpenKeyExW(...) you receive a handle to the subkey. You need to use this received handle NEW_hKey to query data from this subkey: RegQueryValueExW(NEW_hKey, ...) and you need to close the subkey afterwards RegCloseKey(NEW_hKey). Rootkeys never need closing, thereforeRegCloseKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER); is nonsense.

@Halfix, Thank you for telling me that. I have now changed it to RegCloseKey(NEW_hKey); . In my messagebox I am still not getting anything past the NEW_value. What am I missing there? I tried changing the wchar_t NEW_value[1024]; to wchar_t NEW_value[8]; for length of ABCDEFG +1. It showed up correctly but the rest of the message is missing. I think that I am somehow handling NEW_value wrong. I have not found documentation on this. How should I fix my code for this? Thank you.

Show the latest version of the code you really use; show the regkey and its content (screenshot); show the output or your result dialog (screenshot)

[ABCDEFG] + 1 is 10 in length. If you provide a non-sufficient reception buffer of just  8 characters weird things may happen. Why didn't you stick with wchar_t NEW_value[1024];? A REG_SZ should contain a terminating 0-char so a bigger size of the reception buffer will never hurt. If you want to be 100% safe you could fill the reception buffer with 0-chars initially using memset()

@Halfix, Yes, ABCDEFG is 7 letters with a +1 for the null = 8. Thank you. It would be helpful if you showed me how to use memset() here in this program code. I am struggling with it.

wchar_t NEW_value[1024]; std::memset(NEW_value, 0, sizeof NEW_value);
